# replacing polyfill of detecting empty object

Tags: javascript, object

I've found some places in code where this is used:

```
Object.keys(o).length === 0
```

This is being used to detect an empty object - can we successfully replace it with

```
JSON.stringify(o) === '{}'
```

Is there any performance gain on doing this? Because option 1 seems like an overkill to me

Comment: yes you can use it for like weight objects(lesser no of nested properties), but I recommand `Object.keys(o).length === 0` to detect empty objects

Comment: Checking the number of object keys _"seems like overkill"_ but stringifying the entire object and comparing it to a string literal does not? I mean, sure, whatever floats your boat ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance gain - quite the opposite. Constructing a possibly-empty array is much more lightweight than recursively searching through all key-value pairs and constructing a string from them.

Even when the object in question *is* a plain empty object, `JSON.stringify` is an order of magnitude slower:

```js
const o = {};
const p0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  Object.keys(o).length === 0
}
const p1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  JSON.stringify(o) === '{}'
}
const p2 = performance.now();

console.log(p1 - p0);
console.log(p2 - p1);
```

(on Chrome-based browsers, at least, on FF, `JSON.stringify` is only about 3 times slower, for me)

Something that looks like *might* be a bit faster than the construction of an array with `Object.keys` would be to use a `for..in` loop, eg

```
function isEmpty(o) {
  for (const key in o) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```js
const o = {};
const p0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  Object.keys(o).length === 0
}
const p1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  for (const key in o) {
    continue;
  }
}
const p2 = performance.now();

console.log(p1 - p0);
console.log(p2 - p1);
```

The above `for..in` is, on my machine, an order of magnitude faster on FF, and about 1/4th faster on Chrome.

(but note that the logic is not quite the same, because `for..in` iterates over inherited keys as well)

Comment: brilliant - I'm gonna use the 1st option then. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify(o) === '{}'` serialize the object into string and its always performane wise costlier than  `Object.keys(o).length === 0`. For positive scenarios it will not show much difference but, consider negative scenarios with multiple keys and its nested values OR just single key holding nested objects.